# DMD 2 on Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, d, dmd

Has anyone tried the Digitalmars D compiler (version 2) on Snow Leopard? I'd like to upgrade but I'd rather have a working D compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you still don't know for sure then just take a deep breath and go for it already:

[Changes in snow since leopard (according to wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_v10.6#Changes_and_improvements). Most snow bugs with various software I have heard so far have been graphics issues. You can ignore a lot of those as dmd is entirely command line.

The Mac OS X port of dmd is fairly recent and working on leopard. Walter documented most of the issues of the port [part 1](http://dobbscodetalk.com/index.php?option=com_myblog&show=Porting-D-to-the-Mac.html&Itemid=29), [part 2](http://dobbscodetalk.com/index.php?option=com_myblog&show=Porting-D-to-the-Mac-Pt.-2.html&Itemid=29), [part 3](http://dobbscodetalk.com/index.php?option=com_myblog&show=Porting-D-to-the-Mac-Pt.-3.html&Itemid=29), [epilog](http://dobbscodetalk.com/index.php?option=com_myblog&show=Porting-D-to-the-Mac-Epilog.html&Itemid=29)

An initial tester is required and you can do Walter a favor by testing for him, dmd gets bug fixes really quick. If it didn't work you can be sure it won't lay not working for very long. With the entire source available you may even be able to submit the patches if any yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-issue at this point, but I will take a moment to plug my favorite implementation (and arguably the easiest way to get D running on OS X): [D For Xcode](http://michelf.com/projects/d-for-xcode/).

Answer (score 0):

[Link](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/dmg_for_Snow_Leopard_x86_64_96009.html) to discussion on the digitalmars.D newsgroup. No news yet, though.

Answer (score -1):

i suggest that you try LDC instead. DMD isnt very stable on linux, etc. DMD also dont have support for 64bit.

Comment: DMD is quite stable in Linux. OS X I think it is doing better, but I don't use it there.

Comment: Oh. I forgot to mention that I'm looking for D2 support.